# Why can't I uninstall CocoaPods?

Tags: terminal, cocoapods

I have never used CocoaPods before. I have installed CocoaPods gems and now I want to delete them but it won't allow me to.

I've attempted to uninstall them by running the command,

```
$ gem uninstall cocoapods
```

Then it asked me if I wanted to remove executables [Yn]. I selected Y. I expected it to remove the CocoaPods. Instead it gave me the error:

> 'ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>       You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/bin directory.'

What does this error mean and how can I remove the CocoaPods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current user probably doesn't have write permissions to `/usr/local/bin`. If you want, you can check the permissions like so:

```
$ ls -ld /usr/local/bin
drwxrwxr-x  573 aaronbrager  admin  18336 Dec 14 09:32 /usr/local/bin
```

And see who you're logged in as like so:

```
$ whoami
aaronbrager
```

In your case, I'm guessing they're different.

Anyway, you can

- fix the permissions (using `chown` and `chmod`),
- change users (login as someone else), or
- just use `sudo`, assuming you have the admin password

I'm guessing this will be easiest for you:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```